# Getting cookies from different domains of same company's sites

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have two websites,for example, one is www.example.com and second is m.example.com. When I redirect from m.example.com to www.example.com, I do not get my session. Is there any possible way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared session concept here in ur case - 
- Save session in DB and access it.
- Share session save folder across your application.

(I m not allowed to add notes so added above as answer)